# Why does this activerecord find query throw an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
@movies = Movie.find(:all, :order => (params[:sort]))
```

Error: Couldn't find all Movies with 'id': (all, {:order=>"title"})

```
@movies = Movie.all.order(params[:sort])
```

Works.

Checked here, and the first snippet seems it should valid:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class

Comment: Which version of Rails you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error: Couldn't find all Movies with 'id': (all, {:order=>"title"})

```
@movies = Movie.find(:all, :order => (params[:sort]))
```

That's because the above query only works in **Rails 2.x** and older. In the *later versions of Rails* that query won't work!

> Checked here, and the first snippet seems it should valid:
>   https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class

You are looking into **older version of Rails(2.3.8)**. You can find the reference to newer versions [*here*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find)

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method would wonder the parameters as the value of the primary key, in most case is `id`, so you should provide the id as int, string or array in most case.